# How can I make Safari stop webpages from overriding any shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

I sometimes need to edit pages on WikiDot, but WikiDot overrides the <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut (and many others), which is a *system-wide* shortcut I often use due to the lack of an <kbd>end</kbd>-key on my keyboard.

Is there a way to stop all webpages from overriding any shortcuts?

Comment: Just a heads up, command-right and command-left are shortcuts for end and home resp.

Comment: not really a solution, but these key parsers are Javascript based, so disable JS.  Unfortunately (or fortunately as some people will have you believe) you will probably find a lot of functionality is removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to prevent this behavior on a web page.

1. Preferred method - Use the settings on the Web App to disable or change shortcut keybindings.
2. Use a third-party Safari extension that allows you to modify the keybindings for javascript.
3. Disable Javascript in Safari.

Comment: Can you post any links for a Safari extension that can do this?